# Find Wordpress hooks and filters using Vim or similar

Tags: wordpress, bash, unix, vim

Wordpress allows you to extend its core using "hooks" and "filters." For example, to execute something quite early in the execution process I may write

```
add_action( 'init', function() { // Do something } );
```

Filters work similarly. The function that defines a hook is `do_action`, so to create the init hook a core developer wrote

```
do_action( 'init' );
```

do_action accepts several optional arguments that this hook doesn't demonstrate. The function names for filters are add_filter and apply_filter.

Say I'm browsing the source code of some plugin and it's using a hook from one of the source files and I don't know which one. What is the easiest way to locate it?

In Vim I use ctags a lot and I was hoping that it was possible to do something similar, only instead of giving the function name I could give the filter or hook name. Any ideas?

(If it can't be done from within Vim, like ctags, second best would be to run a command that will locate the script for me. This could also be acceptable if it is the best solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the basic to the rather involved:

**GREP**

Already explained.

**GREP FROM VIM OR VIMGREP**

If you are already in Vim, you can use the `:vimgrep` command or its sister `:grep`:

```
:vim "do_action( 'init' )" **/*.php | copen
```

See `:help starstar` for the `**` wildcard that let's you do recursive search. `:vimgrep` uses an internal method while `:grep` uses, well… `grep`. The latter may be faster.

**CTAGS**

Assuming you have `ctags` installed, the indexing can be done in the shell or in Vim:

```
$ ctags -R . <-- in the shell
:!ctags -R . <-- in Vim
```

and the querying is just a matter of `:tag do_action`. Read `:help tags` for an indepth explanation.

**CSCOPE**

Assuming you have `cscope` installed, you can use it right from the shell:

```
$ cscope -R *.php
```

Once the index is created you can search in `cscope`'s interface and open the chosen files in your editor.

Assuming your Vim comes with cscope support, you have to:

1. create the index, `:!cscope -bR *.php`
2. locate the index, `:cs add cscope.out`
3. *f*ind the *d*efinition, `:cs f d do_action`

There are other specialized tools like [Codesearch](https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/) or [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) but I think that you don't really need to go further than plain `grep` or, at most, `ctags`.

Comment: The ctags and cscope examples find the definition of do action, right? I want to know where do_action is being used with a certain argument, 'init' for example. Could this be achieved with ctags or cscope?

Comment: No, AFAIK it's outside of their scope. `cscope` can perform regexp search but I've never even tried to use it. `grep` or some similar solution like `ack` is your best bet, I think. That's how I'd do it, from outside Vim anyway, exactly like in @s_ha_dum answer. Also I use a Vim plugin called CtrlP which, among other cool things, allows me to perform fuzzy search on my global `tags`. Using it, it would only be a matter of `,Tini<cr>`, I think, which is quite possibly the quickest way to reach `do_action( 'init' )` anywhere in your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

> Say I'm browsing the source code of some plugin and it's using a hook
>   from one of the source files and I don't know which one. What is the
>   easiest way to locate it?

I use grep. Couldn't work without it. `grep` gets me just about anything I want. `grep -Rni "do_action( 'init'" *` should find the 'init' hook. You can use regex in the search string if you need to as well as tell it to ignore particular files and/or directories. I've tried other options but just haven't ever been sold on anything else. `grep` is quick and clean.

This isn't a 'Vim' answer but you did say 'or similar' :)

There is a very good hook database at http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/version/3.4 too.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this quite a lot lately so I wrote [a little Vim plugin](https://github.com/borzhemsky/wp-hook-finder) to ease the process.

Simply place the caret on name of the hook or filter, press <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find the hooked functions, or <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the hook/filter definition.

To install:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle && git clone https://github.com/borzhemsky/wp-hook-finder.git
```

Add the keybindings to ~/.vimrc:

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :FindWPHook<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>F :FindWPHookDef<CR>
```

**Site note:** Writing this taught me that, yes, people do things like using `add_filter` hook their functions to hooks defined with `do_action`, so searching for occurrences manually can be error-prone.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for sharing it. Incidentally, I noticed that when using this on "dynamic" filters (not sure if that's the right term), e.g. (in the genesis framework) `genesis_attr_{context}` (where `context` could be e.g. `site-header`), it did not return any results (expected). Do you know if there's a way to modify this to be more "greedy" if no exact matches are found? I'm not familiar enough with ack to know where to start.

Comment: @tnorthcutt Happy to hear you like it! I've updated the code (now linked above as a vim plugin) so it matches these contextual filters: searching with caret over `genesis_attr_site-header` will now list all filters starting with `genesis_attr_site-`. Vim considers a dash as a word boundary, so unfortunately, everything that follows the dash is not included as a search term.

Comment: Just a quick note here to point you (and anyone else) to wordpress.vim: https://github.com/dsawardekar/wordpress.vim. Specifically, the latest release as of this writing has filter/hook integration: http://pressing-matters.io/wordpress-vim-gets-wordpress-hooks-integration/